# Defining a function from an expression stored in a var

Tags: clojure

I asked a similar question yesterday but it seemed I had to change my approach, so I did, but now I'm sort of stuck again.

Anyway, what I want to do is something along the line of

```
(def bar '(* 2 %))
(#(bar) 2) ;this line doesn't work.
(#(* 2 %) 2) ;this is what I want the line that doesn't work to do.
```

Thing is, I want the expression stored in a var so I could do something like

```
(def bar2 (list (first bar) 3 (nth bar 2)))
(#(bar2) 2) ;this line obviously doesn't work either.
```

Maybe there's another approach than the `#` anonymous function reader macro.

I'm doing a project in genetic programming for uni so what I need to do is have an expression that I can change and make into a function.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't generate `(fn [x] (* 2 x))`? Even if you're getting it as a list at runtime for some reason, you can put it through eval just once to generate a function and then store and reuse that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(def bar '(* 2 %))

((eval (read-string (str "#" bar))) 3)
=> 6
```

If you used named parameter(s) in expression it would look cleaner:

```
(def bar '(* 2 p))

(def f-expr (concat '(fn [p]) [bar]))

((eval f-expr) 3)
=> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate quoted expressions at *run time* (as opposed to compile time, à la macros), you can just use [`eval`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/eval):

```
(eval '(* 10 12))
;=> 120

(def arg 12)
(def bar '(* 10 arg))
(eval bar)
;=> 120
```

Normally one steers clear of `eval` (macros will perform better, for one thing), but it might be what you want for playing with genetic algorithms.